# Convergence to identity of "Feynman-Kac" operator

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, operator-theory, brownian-motion

$\newcommand\R{\mathbb R}
\newcommand\E{\mathbf E}$
Consider the family of operator $(F_T:T>0)$ on $L^2(\R)$ defined as
$$F_Tf(x)=\E\left[f(x+B_T)\exp\left(-\int_0^T|x+B_t|~dt\right)\right],$$
where $B$ is a standard Brownian motion on $[0,T]$ and the expected value $\E$ is taken with respect to $B$.

I'm trying to understand why $F_0$ can be considered the identity operator,
more precisely,
I want to show that
$$\lim_{T\downarrow0}\|F_Tf-f\|_2^2=0.$$

My first instinct is to use the dominated convergence theorem.
This works well for half of the solution:
if we take $f$ continuous (should be no problem since we're in $L^2$),
then
$$f(x+B_T)\to f(x)$$
and
$$\exp\left(-\int_0^T|x+B_t|~dt\right)\to 1$$
almost surely,
so
$$\E\left[f(x+B_T)\exp\left(-\int_0^T|x+B_t|~dt\right)\right]-f(x)\to0$$
pointwise
(that the dominated convergence theorem applies here is trivial).

However,
the problem is to then apply dominated convergence to the integral
$$\int_0^\infty\left(\E\left[f(x+B_T)\exp\left(-\int_0^T|x+B_t|~dt\right)\right]-f(x)\right)^2d x.$$
Try as I might, I have absolutely no idea how to dominate the inner function as an integrable function in $x$. Any idea would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the inequality $(a-b)^2\leq 2(a^2+b^2)$ where $a$ is your expectation and $b$ is $f(x)$. This means you only need to show that the expectation is square integrable, since you already know $f$ is square integrable. Furthermore the inequality $E(X)^2\leq E(X^2)$ means you only need to show that $E(\dots^2)$ is integrable. Since the random variable inside the expectation is now non-negative, Fubini's theorem can be applied to switch the expectation and the integral. The Cauchy-Schwarz inequality applied to the integral (which now lies inside the expectation) will tell you that you are taking the expectation of a uniformly bounded random variable.